# How can I configure my mouse side buttons to control volume?Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mouse, volume-control, button

The mouse is a Bazalias X1 and I have determined the buttons are numbers 8 and 9.

This is for a PC that is mostly used for media, running Ubuntu 16.04 with the Gnome MPV player. I would like to control all audio applications this way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use xbindkeys and xdotool to do this.

1. Install

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xdotool
   ```
2. Create a a default ~/.xbindkeysrc

   ```
   xbindkeys -d > ~/.xbindkeysrc
   ```
3. In the ~/.xbindkeysrc, add these lines:

   ```
   # Adjust volume with mouse buttons
   "xdotool key XF86AudioLowerVolume"
       b:8
   "xdotool key XF86AudioRaiseVolume"
       b:9
   ```
4. Start xbindkeys

   ```
   xbindkeys
   ```
5. The buttons will now adjust volume
6. In Startup Applications, add an entry to autostart xbindkeys on login:

   - Name: xbindkeys
   - Command: `xbindkeys_autostart`

Answer (score 2):

**Optimal solution**

```
"xdotool keydown XF86AudioLowerVolume"
b:8

"xdotool keyup XF86AudioLowerVolume"
b:8 + Release

"xdotool keydown XF86AudioRaiseVolume"
b:9

"xdotool keyup XF86AudioRaiseVolume"
b:9 + Release

"xdotool key XF86AudioPlay"
b:2
```

This will behave as the keyboard keys as it will continue changing up/down the volume until you release the mouse button.

Happy coding...