# How to make "x" act as mouse left click if scroll lock on?

Tags: scripts, autokey

I know this is possible with AutoHotKey but that isn't available on Ubuntu, unless you use Wine, but I want to try to get it working without Wine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `xbindkeys` and `xdotool`. Once you have them both installed, and an ~/.xbindkeysrc file set up:

1. Edit ~/.xbindkeysrc
2. Uncomment this line:

   ```
   #keystate_scrolllock= enable
   ```
3. Add these lines:

   ```
   # x -> left click (when Scroll Lock is on)
   "xdotool click 1"
       Mod5 + x
   ```

I can't test this on my machine because I don't have Scroll Lock, but I do have some shortcuts that are only active when Num Lock is off. So let me know how it goes!

For more details about the installation and setup, see my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/961699/301745), specifically steps 1 and 2, then after editing xbindkeysrc, steps 4 and 6.